# How to copy all the files in a specific folder and then concatenate them into one file?

Tags: shell

I would like to improve my shell script skills. What I want to do is that I will copy all the files in a specific folder into other destination folder and then save them into one file by concatenating them.

Below is my simple code.

```
path=/Users/sclee/Dropbox/project/java/projects/WaferPointDraw/src/main/resources/pattern
dest=/Users/sclee/Dropbox/journal/clustering_ieee_semi_2020/data/small_datasets/noise200000other2000
output=large_datast_3.txt

mkdir -p $dest;
echo "$dest directory is created"
for i in `find ${path} -iname '*.txt'`;
do
        cp $i $dest;
done
echo "all the files is copied"

cat ${dest}/* > ${dest}/${output}
echo "created the combined file"
```

I can achieve my goals with above codes, but I would like to process all the logic in the for loop. As you can see, the `cat` command is done apart from the for loop. I would like to process  them in the `for` loop for the simple code.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: To improve your shell skills, read this: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 -- don't read lines with `for`

Comment: More reading: [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Answer (score 0):

Oneliner using `find` :

```
find "$path" -iname '*.txt' -exec cp {} "$dest" \; -exec sh -c "cat {} >> $dest/$output" \;
```

Comment: The last clause could be `-exec cat {} + > "$dest/$output"` I think

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right you could replace

```
do
  cp $i $dest;
done
```

with

```
do
  cat $i>>${dest}/${output};
done
```

That appends the findings to your output file

Comment: The Q says "copy and cat", so keep the cp command in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

question: the txt files in $path, are there subdirectories into which you want to descend in order to find all the txt files? If not, you don't need `find`, `for file in "$path"/*.txt` will suffice.

In fact, you don't need a loop if all the files are in one directory:

```bsh
cp -t "$dest" "$path"/*.txt
cat "$path"/*.txt > "$dest/$output"
```

Note that a variable in braces `${var}` is not the same as a quoted variable `"$var"`